# If (IBAction)buttonPressed, setupGame - How?

Tags: ios, ibaction

I would like to setup my Game if the button was pressed for the first time. Or a other option is, to setup the Game if the points are above 0. How ever, I want to do this, but I don´t know how. Can you help me out?

BTW: I´ve just began programming with this app and I would love it if you could already integrate the solution in my code..

XCode Project -> http://techstern.de/app/KlickMich.zip 
Screenshot -> http://techstern.de/app/screenshot2.png


Translation of german words:
Zeit -> Time
Punktestand -> Score
KlickMich -> TapMe
Die Zeit ist um -> Time is up
Du hast 12 Punkte erzielt -> You´ve scored 12 points
Auf Facebook teilen -> Share on Facebook
Auf Twitter teilen -> Share on Twitter

#### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.m"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;

NSInteger count;
NSInteger seconds;
NSTimer *timer;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed;
- (void)setupGame;
- (void)subtractTime;
- (void)postToTwitter;
- (void)postToFacebook;

@end
```

#### ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self setupGame];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed{
count++;

scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Punktestand: %li",(long)count];

}

- (void)setupGame{
seconds = 15;
count = 0;

timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zeit: %li",(long)seconds];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Punktestand: %li",(long)count];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(subtractTime)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

}

- (void)subtractTime{
seconds--;
timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zeit: %li",(long)seconds];

if (seconds == 0) {
[timer invalidate];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Die Zeit ist um"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Du hast %li Punkte erzielt",(long)count]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Nochmal spielen"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Auf Facebook teilen", @"Auf Twitter teilen", nil];

[alert show];
} 

}

[…]
```

Yours faithfully 
Robin

Comment: i think i solved your problem. Again what's your problem?

Comment: Yeah you solved my other problem, but I don´t want that the game is immediately starting after launching the app, so I had the idea, once the "KlickMich"/"TapMe" button was pressed for the first time, the game can begin...

Comment: ok i'll solve your prob. wait :)

Comment: I will wait, but please configure your answer as answer and not as comment so I can verify it ;) - With kind regards

Comment: Sorry I can´t explain the question more than I already have, but David R. will find the solution I think. Anyway thanks for your demand - Yours faithfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

Declare your [self setupGame]; method in `buttonPressed` action instead of `- (void)viewDidLoad` like below.

```
 - (IBAction)buttonPressed
 {
   if (count == 0)
   {
      [self setupGame];
   }
   count++;
   scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Punktestand: %li",(long)count];
 }
```

And if your `alertview` is coming and you cancel alertview or after share in twitter, your game will reset not waiting for button click. If you want you can change also. no problem :)

Comment: wow, I can´t believe count == 0 can change the world :D, thank you very much ^^ - Yours faithfully

Comment: I´m sorry for it, but I need your help again. I thought the code snippet would also work with the buttonIndex, but there are some problems with this (it counts backwards into the - area. Could you maybe help me with it? It would be cool if we could write in e-mail. Pls contact me if you´re interested in helping me -> robin@techstern.de

Comment: or if you don´t want to write via e-mail, please say how I define the same thing with the alert view and so on...